# PHP Page: No database selected issue

Tags: php, mysql

I get `No database selected on line 13` error. And this code line is

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error." on line ".__LINE__);
```

Database connected successfully but when I try to open "question.php" file I get this error.

```
<?php
     // Set question number
     $number = (int) $_GET['n'];

     /*
     * Get Question
     */
     $query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE questions.question_number = $number";

    // Get Result

    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error." on line ".__LINE__);

    $question = $result->fetch_assoc();


    /*
    * Get Choices
    */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM choices WHERE question_number = $number";

   // Get Results
   $choices = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

?>
```

**UPDATE**!

My database connection:

```
<?php

    // Create connection credentials
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'quizzer';
    $db_user= 'root';
    $db_pass='';

    // Create mysqli object

    $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user,$db_pass,$db_pass);

    // Error handler
    if($mysqli->connect_error){
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
}
```

Comment: Show where you set up your database connection!

Comment: Just updated my question.

Comment: `$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user,$db_pass,$db_pass);` 2 instances of `$db_pass`?? really?? `$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);` perhaps

Comment: Just kill me please. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of things happened to me countless times.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. Using `intval` to scrub values is not a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, write that :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
```

instead of :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user,$db_pass,$db_pass);
```